# Перевод из InputStream в String

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Я извлекаю из части письма `(BodyPart)` содержимое следующим образом:
`bodyPart.getDataHandler().getDataSource().getInputStream()`, мне необходимо извлекать именно так. Я получаю InputStream, мне нужно его перегнать в строку **без** декодирования (т.е. чтобы осталось "как есть").

Иногда там `8-bit/7-bit` кодировка, иногда `base64`.

Я опробовал все методы из этой статьи [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/278233/), но они видоизменяли `inputStream`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение.

Отрывок исходного письма:

```
-Type: image/png; name=logo inline image
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=logo inline image
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <logo>
X-Attachment-Id: 7c408fe710f19880_0.1

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKMAAABdCAYAAADJ9NbpAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJ
bWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAADwZJREFUeNrsnXt0FNUdx+/s5iWKGEsS5VHyEiFFCiYUscDRnlAPaq0S
EiwIra9EIVRATxM8p9b2D5voUbDHF0FtrRICSXiILyQqPmqFGkSq8jDZBM07p4YISBKyM/3e2Vmy
DHd3Z3ZmdrOb+zvnl3nszN3ZuZ/5vebORJAkiXDhMhjExk8BFw4jFy4qifJcEAQhoEYSth6lUMd1
3jLuh6F4EnmoM7gsI+2NvQlbGq7kp5RLSGGERaQw/gv6YWK141f8tHIJdcxYDh0G3ZZYVb+cn1ou
ekXwjHcCjRnPxI2S2IgGxxLapiQ9BV3RkXeZk8eMXIJqGeGqRUw2eqwqhG5P3HTkAn6auQTbTVPZ
```

Отрывок после переведения в строку:

```
�PNG


IHDR�]����tEXtSoftwareAdobe ImageReadyq�e<IDATx���{t�����%�K�Q�!E
&����Pj�,��D!T@O<�����Q��Am�Ix�/$*>j�D��0��;��H�3���Y�wwgvfv���;��y����������D�$�p�2��O#.*��\!�F��P�u�2���xy�3�,#���    [����KHa�E�0��ab��W��r  u�X��XU���Z.zE��w����������$=]��w����\�j��EL6z�*�nO�t�~���MS��Z����I�G�S�%�0v�K9����Sh�����T~���2��#�Q���^�O9M  L��o�E4�-B��a��i0���c�qTIbd�E���e<m���� ��Al��$������;x�0�g�
```

Comment: не могли бы вы привести реальный пример текста письма и результат ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator ещё раз отредактировал вопрос. Сначала приложил не тот пример.

Comment: а вы пробовали считать в byte[]  и потом конвертить в String?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator только что попробовал. new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream)); тоже самое

Comment: очевидно, что здесь не правильная кодировка.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator я тоже так решил и попробовал все из этого списка
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Comment: нужно получить исходную кодировку и потом конвертировать с этой кодировкой

Comment: `getInputStream()` возвращает поток с раскодированным содержимым куска письма, в вашем примере это png файл. Попробуйте [`Part.writeTo`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Part.html#writeTo-java.io.OutputStream-) в `ByteArrayOutputStream` и оттуда уже в ASCII строку